# Getting an error when running awk from a script

Tags: shell-script, awk

I have a file some.txt

```
-rwxrw-r-- 1 ivamshky ivamshky    152 Apr  2 00:42 12.sh~
-rw-rw-r-- 1 ivamshky ivamshky     58 Apr  6 19:03 a.c
-rw-rw-r-- 1 ivamshky ivamshky     98 Apr  1 20:27 all.sh
-rwxrwxr-x 1 ivamshky ivamshky   8509 Apr  6 19:04 a.out
-rw-rw-r-- 1 ivamshky ivamshky     46 Apr  6 19:07 a.py
-rw-rw-r-- 1 ivamshky ivamshky    399 Apr 18 00:37 attendance.csv
-rw-rw-r-- 1 ivamshky ivamshky    341 Apr 20 01:08 attendance.sh
-rw-rw-r-- 1 ivamshky ivamshky      0 Apr 19 16:21 awk
-rw-rw-r-- 1 ivamshky ivamshky    212 Apr 20 01:41 awktest.sh
```

Now, I want that if a filename in current directory is present in above file, then a new coloumn is added to that line having "FOUND".
eg:
if awktest.sh is present in pwd. then the output comes out to be:

```
-rw-rw-r-- 1 ivamshky ivamshky    212 Apr 20 01:41 awktest.sh   FOUND
```

I havve written this script(With your Help, Thanks)

```
 #!/bin/bash
for fn in *
do
    n=$( awk -v fn="$fn" '$0 ~ fn { print NR }' some.txt )
    awk -v n="$n" 'NR==n { $(NF+1)="Found" }1' some.txt >some.out
done
```

but there's no new coloumn is added in the outputfile.(there are some files in pwd which are present in some.txt

Comment: You should show exactly what you've done, how you called it, which shell you're using, versions of the tools, and on which platform you are working.

Comment: Which shell? It works in zsh and bash without any errors.

Comment: It works also in ksh and should work in every POSIX shell.

Comment: I m also using bash. It works when I run this command on terminal. but doesn't work in a script.

Comment: You said already that it fails. - Now, which platform? - Then, how did you call it?

Comment: I'm using Ubuntu 14.04.

Comment: The issue must be here: `awk -F" " 'NR=='"$n"'{OFS=" "; $(NF+1)="Found";}1`. Start with using: `for fn in $list` with a `$`. Then pass variables as: `awk -F" " -v n=$n 'NR==n { ... }'`.

Comment: Yes I found that mistake while Pasting the Code here. But still there's error saying: "awk: line 1: syntax error at or near {"

Comment: Please, PLEASE, fix **and** restructure your code as suggested, then try again, and if there's still issues then edit your question to reflect the new code.

Comment: All suggestions, please! - `awk -F" " -v n=$n 'NR==n { ... }'`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Much easy it can be done with `sed`

```
#!/bin/bash
unset pattern
for fn in *
do
    pattern=${pattern:+${pattern}\\|}$f
done
sed -i "/$pattern/s/$/ Found/" some.txt
```

Comment: Thanks it's working.
but, is there any way to do it with awk because I am doing something with a csv file. Above problem is just like testing.

Also can you tell me what is the Line "pattern=${pattern:+${pattern}\\|}$fn" doing?

Answer (score 1):

The code is very convoluted. For example

```
>>  list=$(ls -l | awk 'NR > 1 { print $9;}')
>>  for fn in $list
```

Why do you do `ls -l` but then extract `$9` (the filename - but note that this does only work if no whitespace is part of the filename); instead of just

```
for fn in *
```

Then you do some `grep` for line numbers and `awk` for field extraction

```
>>  n=`grep -n "$fn" some.txt | awk -F":" '{ print $1;}'`
```

but why not simply let `awk` do the matching

```
n=$( awk -v fn="$fn" '$0 ~ fn { print NR }' some.txt )
```

And finally, instead of switching forth and back between shell and awk by quoting

```
>>  awk -F" " 'NR=='"$n"'{OFS=" "; $(NF+1)="Found";}1' some.txt>some.out
```

pass the variable cleanly as parameter, as in

```
awk -v n="$n" 'NR==n { $(NF+1)="Found" } 1'
```

Now putting those pieces together:

```
for fn in *
do
    n=$( awk -v fn="$fn" '$0 ~ fn { print NR }' some.txt )
    awk -v n="$n" 'NR==n { $(NF+1)="Found" } 1' some.txt >some.out
    mv some.out some.txt
done
```

Not quite sure whether this is exactly what you want, but it's clearer code and should have lesser issues at least.

 Now with this restructuring it seems you can do that all also in just one `awk` instance, it seems. (But I leave that as exercise for the reader.)

Answer (score 0):

```
!/bin/bash
list=$(ls -l | awk 'NR > 1 { print $9;}')
for fn in list 
do
echo $fn
    n=`grep -n "$fn" some.txt | awk -F":" '{ print $1;}'` # change this
    awk -F" " 'NR=='"$n"'{OFS=" "; $(NF+1)="Found";}1' some.txt>some.out
    mv some.out some.txt
done



!/bin/bash
list=$(ls -l | awk 'NR > 1 { print $9;}')
for fn in list; do # also decided to clean this up
    echo $fn
    n=$(grep -n "$fn" some.txt | awk -F":" '{ print $1;}') # to this
    awk -F" " 'NR=='"$n"'{OFS=" "; $(NF+1)="Found";}1' some.txt>some.out # also, what is this line supposed to do? There is usually a better way to do something that have to run a mv command to overwrite
    mv some.out some.txt
done
```

There might be something else, but I haven't had my coffee yet.

http://tldp.org/LDP/Bash-Beginners-Guide/html/sect_03_04.html

Answer (score 0):

Problems in your script:

- [SC2006](https://github.com/koalaman/shellcheck/wiki/SC2006) - Use $(..) instead of legacy `..`.
- [SC2012](https://github.com/koalaman/shellcheck/wiki/SC2012) - Use find instead of ls to better handle non-alphanumeric filenames.
- [SC1035](https://github.com/koalaman/shellcheck/wiki/SC1035) - You are missing a required space after the !.

  ```
  1  !/bin/bash
      ^––SC1035 You are missing a required space after the !.
  2  list=$(ls -l | awk 'NR > 1 { print $9;}')
            ^––SC2012 Use find instead of ls to better handle non-alphanumeric filenames.
  3  for fn in $list 
  4  do
  5  
  6      n=`grep -n "$fn" some.txt | awk -F":" '{ print $1;}'`
           ^––SC2006 Use $(..) instead of legacy `..`.
  7      awk -F" " 'NR=='"$n"'{OFS=" "; $(NF+1)="Found";}1' some.txt>some.out
  8      mv some.out some.txt
  9  done
  ```

[Source](http://www.shellcheck.net/)